# Audio-only HLS skipping with individually-made fmp4 segments

Tags: java, mp4, http-live-streaming, mp4parser, fmp4

Here's my HLS playlist:

- [chunky.m3u8](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky.m3u8)

I'm able to stream that link using [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/). However **I hear a tiny audio error** like "skipping" in between each of the 10-second segments.

Here's my initialization segment:

- [chunky-128k-IS.mp4](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-IS.mp4)

And here are the fragmented mp4 segments generated by encoding AAC audio in `ffmpeg` and then writing only the media fragment to an .m4s using [java mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser):

- [chunky-128k-163840683.m4s](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-163840683.m4s)
- [chunky-128k-163840684.m4s](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-163840684.m4s)
- [chunky-128k-163840685.m4s](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-163840685.m4s)
- [chunky-128k-163840686.m4s](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-163840686.m4s)
- [chunky-128k-163840687.m4s](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-163840687.m4s)
- [chunky-128k-163840688.m4s](https://charneykaye.github.io/hls-fmp4-demo/chunky-128k-163840688.m4s)

Here are detailed lab notes about the process I developed to create these: https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo

Here's the output of `ffprobe chunky.m3u8`:

```
[hls @ 0x55fd1ae10f00] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:7')
[hls @ 0x55fd1ae10f00] Opening 'chunky-128k-IS.mp4' for reading
[hls @ 0x55fd1ae10f00] Opening 'chunky-128k-163840683.m4s' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'chunky.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
      major_brand     : iso5
      minor_version   : 1
      compatible_brands: isomiso5dash
      creation_time   : 2021-12-02T00:21:18.000000Z
```

### Paradox?

I'm reading https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34627/audio-discontinuities-when-generating-hls-segments-in-different-processes "MDCT-based codecs like AAC or MP3 carry out their transforms over multiple adjoining frames" and wonder if maybe the answer is, this is impossible with AAC or MP3 audio, and in fact, because individually generating the media segments ***is*** a constraint, I would need to generate MPEG-2 TS fragments? Or would that not help either?

Comment: Are you re-initializing the encoder for each input file?

Comment: Yes @aergistal -- my use case begins with 10-second media segments written manually to .wav files by a proprietary musical instrument. I have been unable to find the ffmpeg arguments required to encode the next input file continuing the output of the previous ffmpeg execution.

Instead, I've been experimenting with a new approach, where I concatenate those outputs into a byte stream and send it to a ffmpeg process running on its own thread in `-f hls -i pipe:0` mode. This appears to be working much better.

Comment: I am currently working through some weird problem where ffmpeg can only write 7 .ts files, then the 8th is empty, and no more are generated, until I stop the process, when said 8th file appears as expected.

Comment: Yes, re-initializing the encoder for each segment is not the good approach because of AAC audio priming. When I had to do something similar (24/7 audio/video streams) I ended up writing my own custom FFmpeg demuxer.

Comment: Why are you using HLS for input? Wouldn't it make more sense to convert the WAVs to raw audio (PCM) which can be concatenated easily and pipe that as input for the HLS muxer?

Comment: I must have mis-spoke-- what you describe is exactly what I'm doing, piping the PCM raw audio directly to the ffmpeg process. That part seems to be working.

Comment: Can you share the full FFmpeg command?